# Websocket security definition doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have following websocket security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        // You can customize your authorization mapping here.
        //messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/hello").hasRole("ADMIN");

    }

    // TODO: For test purpose (and simplicity) i disabled CSRF, but you should re-enable this and provide a CRSF endpoint.
    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**I expect that only admin can send messages into the `/hello` topic.**
and following security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "rockandroll";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index.html")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/sender.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/lib/**", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/index.html", "/","/*.css","/webjars/**", "/*.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/websocket").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
            }

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD.equals(token.getCredentials()) ?
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN") : null;

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getName(), token.getCredentials(), authorities);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also I have following websocket controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(@Payload HelloMessage message, Principal principal) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/greetings", new Greeting("Ololo"));
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

Next I login as **user/pass**(It is not admin).

And client successfully sends messages to the `/hello` topic:

```
stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()}));
```

and method `greeting`invokes successfully.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It became working after I had provided following definition(added `/app`):

```
messages.simpDestMatchers("/app/hello").hasRole("ADMIN");
```